# Arithmetic calculation using long double in PIC 18F4520

Tags: microcontroller, microchip

**I need to know the maximum size of number (number of decimal digits) that we can multiply using PIC18F4520.**
I am using **long double** because I need a decimal value of high precision and calculations involve 15-17 digits numbers.
What is the maximum rage of number we can multiply?
Or is there any other way.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome! There is no upper limit as long as you have enough RAM to do it. Or are you asking what a single instruction can handle?

Comment: How long a long double is in your compiler, or what formats your compiler supports? Which compiler you are using?

Comment: compiler is xc8 and c 18.  Sorry for being late